# can we covert java .class into .java file then how java is called as a secure lang

Tags: java, security, class, decompiler

Is there is any converter which convert our compiled `.class` (Abc.class) into `.java`(Abc.java). If we can do so then how we called as Java is secure language. Is there is any other way to convert our class into .java file

Am raising the question about the java security also please note that

thank you all

Comment: What are you asking? How to do a web search for "Java decompiler"? Or are you asking about security?

Comment: @ Ted Hopp am asking about security if we can conert our class file into .java file how we can say that java is secure. we can easily extract all class file from a jar. so anyone can get our coding

Comment: "Security through Obscurity" is generally considered to be a Bad Thing.

Comment: I suggest that you rephrase your question so the intent is clear. Almost everyone reading this thought you were asking about how to decompile .class files, and that you threw in the security issue just to kick up some dust. However, be aware that this forum is for asking specific, answerable questions and that questions that are likely to lead to endless debate will be quickly closed (for different reasons than this question was closed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are tools to decompile .class files, such as JAD http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_(JAva_Decompiler)

In that sense, I wouldn't say java is secure if you're distributing your class files. However, there are measures you can take such as using an obfuscator such as ProGuard (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Also note that [C can be decompiled, too](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/index.shtml). I don't want anyone to think it's safe just because it's native code.